# Azure ADB2C - Email MFA showing additonal success page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Am following the tutorial listed in below URL to enable EMAIL MFA

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signin-email-verification

Everything works correctly, except it shows an additional page on Verification success

[image]

This is an extra page that comes after I enter the Verification Code -> Click Verify -> click Continue and then again this page. Need to know how to disable this page. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from the MS community for the same.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/537